# How to remove Sign In' & 'Forgot Password and then adjust width of Email Template to remove white spaces?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to remove 'Sign In' & 'Forgot Password' from attached email template and then adjust the width so that white black spaces be adjusted. Please assist! 
Dear Gortonington,. Awaiting for your reply.
[image]

Comment: This looks like some UI adjustment that you need to make in your template. Do you have any doubt regarding the processing of this email in Marketing Cloud or are you just looking for a solution that adjusts the height and width here?

Comment: Hello Krati, thank you for your time. I want to remove 'Sign In' & 'Forgot Password' from the template. If I do this, there would an empty white space which I don't want. So, my concern is- Can we adjust the width and set to auto (in case we end up removing those 2 links). If this is doable, we will be able to update template to remove the links. Yes, I'm just looking for a solution that adjusts the height and width here if it's removed?
Thanks.!
Samir Sayyad
Capgemini Tech works @ John Deere

Comment: This would require changes to the html. Can you post the code?

Comment: Hello Gortonington, Can we remove 'Sign In' & 'Forgot Password' link from AMP plain text view and save? Would it be reflecting then?

Comment: Awaiting for your reponse Gort...

Answer (score 1):

This is an html question, I can't see your code ,but it seems you have got a table with 5 columns,just edit the html code and remove the  last column (td).

Comment: Thank you very much Albert Seuba. I got it.